# Append content to brotli compressed file

Tags: python, brotli

I am using the brotli compressor and i want to open a compressed file and append more content to it.

Thus far i used the following test:

```
import brotli

for _ in range(2):
    with open('test.br','ab') as fd:
        compressor = brotli.Compressor(mode=brotli.BrotliEncoderMode.TEXT)
        fd.write(compressor.compress("foo"))
        fd.write(compressor.flush())
        fd.write(compressor.finish())
```

However if i decompress

```
$cat test.br | brotli --decompress
foo
```

instead of

`foofoo`

Is there a way to append to a brotli compressed file *without* decompressing previous written content or tell it to skip file headers?